# Do you need to save ManagedObjectContext in order for a Nullify delete rule to affect destination entity?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm saving chessGames and chessPlayers to a DB using core data. 
-Each chessGame has a to-one relationship to a white Player and black player (with a delete rule set to nullify). 
-Each player has to-many relationship to gamesAsWhite and to gamesAsBlack (with a delete rule set to deny).

When ever I delete a chessGame I also try to delete the players involved in that game, if the players are not involved in any other games. As shown in code below.

**Code used to delete chess game and potentially players too:**

```
context.perform {
                //deletes associated chessgameSnapShot
                context.delete(chessGameMO)
                CoreDataUtilities.save(context: context)
                //delete rule set to deny
                //player only deleted if it is not involved in any games
                whitePlayer.deleteIfNotInvolvedInAnyGames(inManagedObjectContext: context)
                blackPlayer.deleteIfNotInvolvedInAnyGames(inManagedObjectContext: context)
                CoreDataUtilities.save(context: context)
            }
```

**Implementation of deleteIfNotInvolvedInAnyGames:**

```
func deleteIfNotInvolvedInAnyGames(inManagedObjectContext context:NSManagedObjectContext){
        guard let gamesAsBlack =  self.gamesAsBlack as? Set<ChessGameMO>,
            let gamesAsWhite =  self.gamesAsWhite as? Set<ChessGameMO> else {return}
        let gamesInvolvedIn = gamesAsWhite.union(gamesAsBlack)
        if gamesInvolvedIn.isEmpty {
            context.delete(self)
        }
    }
```

The code only works if I save the context after I delete the chessGame. If I remove the first  `CoreDataUtilities.save(context: context)` then the `whitePlayer` (and the `blackPlayer`) never get deleted in the `deleteIfNotInvolvedInAnyGames` because the relationship to `chessGameMO` doesn't seem to have nullified yet.

Is this normal behaviour? Shouldn't the relationships between the NSManagedObjects (in memory) be updated before I save the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initial understanding is correct - validation only happens on save.  So if you deleted the game and the player and then saved it should work assuming that all changes are valid. **BUT** the *relationships* are not updated until save.  The relationship is still there, it is just pointing to a deleted object (`object.isDeleted`). So your code in `deleteIfNotInvolvedInAnyGames` has to filter out all deleted objects and then see if the set is empty.

Comment: Ok thats exactly the type of answer I was looking for! Toda Raba!
So the relationships don't update until you save the context. Good to know!